# How to take values from an array by using trim() or split() in java

Tags: java

For example: I've an array like this: ["A-1111","A-2222","A-3333"] 
Now I need to take only the numerical values i.e; 1111,2222,3333 and store in a list using java.

So help me out with this.

```
int a = 0;
        ArrayList<String> vals = packList;
        for(String val : vals){
            a = Integer.parseInt(val.split("-")[1]);
            System.out.print(a);
        }
```

Am able to get the list as 111122223333. But I need it as an array like [1111,2222,3333]

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you know how to access an element in the array? How to declare and define it? How to extract only the number part of the string? How to convert a number in String format to a numeric format? How to iterate over an array? Where to read such things up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is example working code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/tCEHn6):

```
class Test
{
    static int getNumber(String val)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(val.split("-")[1]);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] vals = {"A-1111","B-2222","C-3333"};
        for(String val:vals)
        {
            System.out.println("Numeric part in [" + val + "] is : " + getNumber(val));
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Numeric part in [A-1111] is : 1111
Numeric part in [B-2222] is : 2222
Numeric part in [C-3333] is : 3333
```

***UPDATE:***

Following is updated code as per updated question. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/fT4Oab):

```
class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String[] vals = {"A-1111","B-2222","C-3333"};
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String val:vals)
        {
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(val.split("-")[1]));
        }
        //'result' is the List holding the integer parts
        System.out.println("Numeric parts are : " + result);
    }
}
```

Respective output is as following:

```
Numeric parts are : [1111, 2222, 3333]
```

Comment: Actually I need the numeric part in an array only like : [1111,2222,3333,...]

Answer (score -1):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A-1111");
    list.add("B-2222");
    list.add("C-3333");

    List<Integer> abc  = list.stream()
        .map(x->Integer.parseInt(x.split("-")[1]))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    abc.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

```
1111
2222
3333
```